# Fetch firestore data for a specific app without authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Since I want to fetch data **without authentication** for my app, my security rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

But Firebase said if someone has this **URL** he can **fetch my data**. How could I **save my data**. My app doesn't require authentication. How could I resist other, or what configuration I can set so only my app can fetch it.

**In simple words**,

No one should allow to fetch my app data(firestore) without my app. Where my app doesn't require authentication.

Comment: FYI you're showing Realtime Database rules, but your question is asking about Firestore.  They are not the same product.  But the answer applies the same for both of them (you can't have security rules that allow unauthenticated access but restricted to just your app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't possible.  These things are all exactly the same:

- Accessing data via client SDK without authentication
- Accessing data with the REST API without an authentication token
- Accessing data in any way without using the app itself

If you want to restrict data to your app only, you will need some form of authentication provided by Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Can I pass some sort of key or authentication mechanism for fetching data ?As right now my app simply fetch some records which I gather by putting a lot of effort. but other can copy if they get the url.

Comment: No, that special key could be intercepted if it's embedded in your mobile app.  Anything in your app should be considered public.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use firebase ***Anonymous*** Authentication, This authentication doesn't require user input like email, password, SSO, etc. You can just set the code inside a button to Get Started, So firebase will automatically create a userID for each user.